# Update one column based matching of other two columns with another date frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two dataframes in R: a big one and a small one. The big dataframe has the following structure:

```
ID Date value1 value2
1  Aug  1      2
1  Sep  1      3
2  Aug  3      2
2  Sep  4      3
```

The small one is like this:

```
ID Date value1
1  Aug  2        
2  Aug  5
```

The big dataframe has all the column names of the small one and more. The small one have some new values about *value1*. So my task is to update value1 of the big dataframe based on the matching of *ID* and *Date* with the small one. So, the resultant dataframe should be this one,

```
ID Date value1 value2
1  Aug  2      2
1  Sep  1      3
2  Aug  5      2
2  Sep  4      3
```

Any clue of how to get this done?

Comment: Please remember to share data via `dput()` when using the R tag (hover your mouse over the tag to read the R tag description).

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`, we can join `on` the `ID` and `Date` columns in both datasets and assign (`:=`) the elements in `i.value1` to `value1` in the first dataset (`df1`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, value1 := i.value1, on = .(ID, Date)]
df1
#   ID Date value1 value2
#1:  1  Aug      2      2
#2:  1  Sep      1      3
#3:  2  Aug      5      2
#4:  2  Sep      4      3
```

By placing `i.` in front of `value1` you indicate that `data.table` has to take the values from `value1` of dataframe `df2`.

Answer (score 0):

Can share data via `dput()`?

---

perhaps, something like this should work?

```
df2[match(df1$ID, df2$ID) & match(df1$Date, df2$Date),'value1']
```